# Gmail, Spamcop.net, and Yahoo Axis

Tags: gmail, spamcop

Yesterday I installed Yahoo Axis for Google Chrome. While I haven't used it too much, it looks good. Anyway, moving on, I frequently go over my Spam folder on Gmail to report spam on spamcop.net. What I normally do is simply open the email, view its source, and copy and paste it on Spamcop. I was doing the same this morning and surprise, surprise, it didn't work (Spamcop couldn't process the email headers, etc.) I figured it could be that specific email, so I tried the next one, and it also didn't work. I disabled Axis, opened a new Spamcop tab, and this time both emails were processed correctly.

I did a quick Google search and it doesn't seem like someone has found anything yet. I didn't try forwarding the spam emails directly from Gmail (I've tried doing that in the past with no success), I didn't try on a different browser, I didn't look at the email headers to find differences, etc., etc. Does anybody know what the problem might be?